# Create list of all external files used by master LaTeX document?

Tags: graphics, include, input, external-files

Is there an easy way to create a list of all external files (complete path) which are used by a LaTeX document (and its "sub-documents") by

- `\input`
- `\include`
- `\includegraphics` ?

(may I have forgotten some input sources?)

Comment: You can parse the `.log` file (not very trivial, though). You can also use `strace` or similar tool (but this one counts as hardcore).

Comment: My `dateiliste` package includes a list of TeX files parsed in the document, but without complete path. (And not files used by includegraphics or similar.)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The [snapshot](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/snapshot) package gives you a list of the external dependencies of a LaTeX document. Use it by saying

```
\RequirePackage{snapshot}
```

before the `\documentclass` command (to have the information written to a `.dep` file), or by saying

```
\RequirePackage[log]{snapshot}
```

before the `\documentclass` command (to have the information written to the `.log` file).

Comment: Is there any way to use this information during the LaTeX build? I am trying to include all the distributed `.tex` files during a build using `\usepackage{embedfile}` and `\embedfile{<...>.tex}`...

Answer (score 20):

use the perl script `mkjobtexmf` available with every TeX distribution and run it like

```
mkjobtexmf --jobname <latex file> --cmd-tex pdflatex
```

it creates an file `<latex file>.fls` which shows all used files, e.g. for a testfile named latex6:

```
PWD /home/voss/Documents
INPUT /usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf.cnf
INPUT /usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf/web2c/texmf.cnf
INPUT /usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/latex.fmt
INPUT latex6.tex
OUTPUT latex6.log
INPUT /usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
INPUT /usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
INPUT /usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
INPUT /usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
[ ... ]
```

Comment: Or you can simply run `pdflatex -recorder <latex-file>` to get the same effect. This is what `mkjobtexmf` does behind the scenes.

Comment: sure, what else should it do? However, you can create a texmf tree depending to the job which is more what `-recorder` can do.

Comment: the `-recorder` option is great !

Comment: `-recorder` works better than `mkjobtexmf` when it comes to pgf plots. With `-recorder` you also get the input files used by pgf for the plots, whereas you dont with `mkjobtexmf `

Comment: Both ways work for me, but I end up with what seems like every line duplicated, so I used [this technique with awk](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/30178/10587). It helped a lot, but I still have things like "filename" and "./filename". I'm trying to make a list of files to bundle up to send to a publisher (who won't download TeXlive?), and I'd like to reduce the list as much as possible.

Comment: @LevBishop Excellent: as far as I'm concerned `-recorder` is The Answer. If this were an answer I'd up-vote it.

Answer (score 11):

This is a modified version of the @Gonzales answer with an additional `python` code to copy the figures to a new folder.

After using `snapshot` package to generate the `.dep` file:

```
\RequirePackage{snapshot}
\documentclass{article}
```

use the following `python` code (say `copy_figs.py`) to copy the figures to a separate folder (for example, `figs_used`):

```
"""Copy figures used by document."""
import os
import shutil


DEP_FILE = 'main.dep'
TARGET_DIR = 'other_img/'
EXTENSIONS = ['pdf', 'pdf_tex', 'png']


def copy_image_files():
    with open(DEP_FILE, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            if '*{file}' not in line:
                continue
            value = line.split('{')[2].split('}')
            source = value[0]
            _, e = os.path.splitext(source)
            e = e.lower()[1:]
            if e not in EXTENSIONS:
                continue
            print(source)
            shutil.copy(source, TARGET_DIR)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    copy_image_files()
```

To run the `python` code:

```
c:\Python27\python.exe copy_figs.py
```

in the folder where the Latex file is placed. It is assumed the original figures are in `figs` subfolder, and those figures used in the Latex file are copied to `figs_used` subfolder. The code copies `.png` and `.pdf` figure files.

Comment: Extremely useful piece of code. Easy to filter with `if '*{file}' not in line:`.

Comment: This is piece of gold. For inclusion of tables that are in other files, you could add ```or re.search(r'\.code\.tex',source) or source=="xkeyval.tex"``` to the last if statement of the function and ```tex```obviously to the extensions. Edited it also for my other needs, full code can be accessed here https://gist.github.com/samuelsaari/99f3ffe35a63482698571d713e9ee594

Answer (score 9):

If you put `\listfiles` as the very first line of the master file, the name of every used file is dumped to standard output, including style and font definition files. This is plain old LaTeX.

Answer (score 8):

`latexmk` does a good job with this:

```
latexmk -deps main.tex
```

It prints everything: other `.tex` files, `.bib` files, `.sty` files, graphics.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a quick-and-dirty implementation of a different approach, that does not require modifications of the source code, nor even recompilation. It just parses the log file, and needs a Unix-like command-line. Just run the following command from a terminal:

```
~ egrep -o '\./[^>) ]*' document.log
```

Caveats:

- it only detect **relative** files
- it will not work with funny file names (spaces or > or parentheses)

Comment: It does not list the figures.