# providing a list of figure filenames used in tex file

Tags: floats, external-files

Is there a simple way of getting a list of figure filenames from a tex file? for example if I have included 10 png, 5 pdf and 3 eps files, is there a script that can output the filenames to a list so I can make sure they all get kept/moved to a different directory together? I've looked at the extract package, but that produces a tex file with the figure code extracted. I guess I can use 'grep', such as cat my.tex | grep eps, but just checking there isn't a standard tex command to do this.

Comment: Take a look at [Create list of all external files used by master LaTeX document?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24542/create-list-of-all-external-files-used-by-master-latex-document)

Comment: If you mean the snapshot package, this seems to list all tex and other files used, rather than just the figures.  Grep works OK as long as you specify all image files.

Comment: `\listfiles` in LaTeX could help. I would check the `log` file.

Answer (score 9):

the built in `\listfiles` does this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\listfiles
\begin{document}

\includegraphics{ug}

\includegraphics{eg2}

\includegraphics{foo}

\end{document}
```

produces a log of:

```
  ug.png    Graphic file (type png)
 eg2.png    Graphic file (type png)
 foo.pdf    Graphic file (type pdf)
```

On my system which happens to have files of those names.