# List of images used in the document latex

Tags: floats, lists, files

I have written a book and inserted a lot of illustrations. All illustrations are input in my document as:

```
\begin{center}
\includegraphics [scale=1]{image/1_12.pdf}
\end{center}
```

I have about 500 images/illustrations

I would like to have the list of all inserted images/illustration, something like:

1_12.pdf

1_23.pdf

test.pdf

and so on.
Is it possible to do that? Thanks a lot for the answer.

Comment: `\listoffigures` generates exactly this, a list of figures. If you insert your illustrations with `\begin{figure}` and `\end{figure}` you can compile a nice list.

Comment: Think OP is wanting a list of the files used not a table of captions. You can get this from the log. See \listfiles http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/152765/providing-a-list-of-figure-filenames-used-in-tex-file