# Generate a list of figure numbers and filenames from \includegraphics

Tags: graphics, floats, external-files

For a book project with lots of figures, I need to generate a list of the filenames of all figures included via `includegraphics{}` **and their figure numbers**.  Something like:

```
1.1 ch01-intro/fig/lascaux.jpg
1.2 ch01-intro/fig/plot-weather-new.png
1.3 ch01-intro/fig/huygens1669.png
1.4 ch01-intro/fig/priestley-chart-biography-edit.png
```

There is a `perl` script on CTAN, [texdepend](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/texdepend?lang=en), that will find the filenames, but it doesn't necessarily list them in order and doesn't grok the figure numbers. (It was designed for generating a `Makefile`, or preparing a ZIP file for a LaTeX project.)

```
> texdepend -format=1 -print=f TOGS.tex |head
# C:\batchfiles\texdepend.pl, v0.96 (Michael Friendly (friendly@yorku.ca))
# commandline: C:\batchfiles\texdepend.pl -format=1 -print=f TOGS.tex
# FIGS =
ch05-playfair/fig/playfair1805-inquiry-crop.jpg
ch01-intro/fig/lascaux.jpg
ch01-intro/fig/plot-weather-new.png
ch01-intro/fig/huygens1669.png
ch01-intro/fig/priestley-chart-biography-edit.png
ch01-intro/fig/marey-trains.png
ch01-intro/fig/Minard-cotton3.png
```

Similar questions have be asked [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/152765/providing-a-list-of-figure-filenames-used-in-tex-file) and [there](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/203306/how-to-get-a-list-of-the-filenames-of-the-figures-embedded-in-a-document) but none have the requirement of including the figure numbers.

**Wanted**: A way to modify `includegraphics` itself so that it also writes lines to an external file, of the form

```
fignum filename
```

One small complication is that a given `begin{figure}` environment can contain two or more `\includegraphics` commands, for example:

```
\begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.49\textwidth]{\theChapter/fig/galton-interp2}
    \includegraphics[width=.49\textwidth]{\theChapter/fig/galton-interp3}
    \caption{A reconstruction of Galton's method for finding contours of
        approximately equal frequency in the relationship between heights of parents
        and their children. 
    }%
    \label{fig:galton-interp2}
\end{figure}
```

If this generates Fig. 6.16, the result should look like

```
6.16 ch06-scat/fig/galton-interp2.png
6.16 ch06-scat/fig/galton-interp3.png
```

Comment: The redefinition of the `\includegraphics` macro is not the real problem concerning the writing of the figure number and the file name, but determination of the figure number itself which is increased by `\caption` which is done later than `\includegraphics` here, unless you use it before...

Comment: There is another, more difficult, problem here: `includegraphics()` by itself, doesn't have access to the filename extensions-- they could be `.png`, `.jpg` or `pdf` for pdflatex.

Comment: That's true......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This redefines `\includegraphics` by adding more code at the end, artifically increasing the `figure` number (within a group) and writing to a `ToC` like file with `\addtocontents` to have the benefit of the `ToC` mechanism with the `\tf@...` file handles.

The file will be named `\jobname.lfn` and is only written if `\listoffigurenumbernames` is used.

Remove the `demo` option for the real use - case, I put it in there since I don't have the various graphics files on my disk.

```
\documentclass{book}


\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}


\LetLtxMacro\davidsincludegraphics\includegraphics

\makeatletter
\RenewDocumentCommand{\includegraphics}{O{}m}{%
  \davidsincludegraphics[#1]{#2}%
  \begingroup
  \advance\c@figure by \@ne
  \addtocontents{lfn}{\thefigure\space #2}
  \endgroup
}

\def\@starttocbutdonotshowit#1{%
  \begingroup
    \makeatletter
    \if@filesw
      \expandafter\newwrite\csname tf@#1\endcsname
      \immediate\openout \csname tf@#1\endcsname \jobname.#1\relax
    \fi
    \@nobreakfalse
  \endgroup}


\newcommand{\listoffigurenumbernames}{%
  \@starttocbutdonotshowit{lfn}%
}

\begin{document}
\listoffigurenumbernames

\chapter{First}

\begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.49\textwidth]{\thechapter/fig/galton-interp2}
    \includegraphics[width=.49\textwidth]{\thechapter/fig/galton-interp3}
    \caption{A reconstruction of Galton's method for finding contours of
        approximately equal frequency in the relationship between heights of parents
        and their children. 
    }%
    \label{fig:galton-interp2}
\end{figure}


\begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.49\textwidth]{\thechapter/fig/galton-interp4}
    \includegraphics[width=.49\textwidth]{\thechapter/fig/galton-inter5}
    \caption{A reconstruction of Galton's method for finding contours of
        approximately equal frequency in the relationship between heights of parents
        and their children. 
    }%
    \label{fig:galton-interp4}
\end{figure}

\chapter{Second}

\begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.49\textwidth]{\thechapter/fig/galton-interp6}
    \includegraphics[width=.49\textwidth]{\thechapter/fig/galton-inter7}
    \caption{A reconstruction of Galton's method for finding contours of
        approximately equal frequency in the relationship between heights of parents
        and their children. 
    }%
    \label{fig:galton-interp5}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

This gives

```
1.1 1/fig/galton-interp2
1.1 1/fig/galton-interp3
1.2 1/fig/galton-interp4
1.2 1/fig/galton-inter5
2.1 2/fig/galton-interp6
2.1 2/fig/galton-inter7
```

**Improved version**

With 'heuristic' determination of file extension for `.jpg`, `.pdf` or `.pdf`

The `\includegraphics` macro has a 4th optional argument which can be used in order to override the file extension.

```
\documentclass{book}


\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}


\LetLtxMacro\davidsincludegraphics\includegraphics

\makeatletter

\RenewDocumentCommand{\includegraphics}{sO{}mo}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
    \davidsincludegraphics*[#2]{#3}%
  }{%
    \davidsincludegraphics[#2]{#3}%
  }%
  \begingroup
  % Trying to determine the extension
  \def\loc@l@ext{}
  \IfValueTF{#4}{%
    \def\loc@l@ext{#4}%
  }{%
    \IfFileExists{#3}{%
    }{%
      \IfFileExists{#3.pdf}{%
        \edef\loc@l@ext{.pdf}%
      }{%
        \IfFileExists{#3.jpg}{%
          \edef\loc@l@ext{.jpg}%
        }{%
          \edef\loc@l@ext{.png}%
        }%
      }%
    }%
  }%
  \advance\c@figure by \@ne
  \addtocontents{lfn}{\thefigure\space #3\loc@l@ext}
  \endgroup
}

\def\@starttocbutdonotshowit#1{%
  \begingroup
    \makeatletter
    \if@filesw
      \expandafter\newwrite\csname tf@#1\endcsname
      \immediate\openout \csname tf@#1\endcsname \jobname.#1\relax
    \fi
    \@nobreakfalse
  \endgroup}


\newcommand{\listoffigurenumbernames}{%
  \@starttocbutdonotshowit{lfn}%
}



\begin{document}
\listoffigurenumbernames

\chapter{First}

\begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.49\textwidth]{galton-interp2}[.png]
    \includegraphics[width=.49\textwidth]{galton-interp3}
    \caption{A reconstruction of Galton's method for finding contours of
        approximately equal frequency in the relationship between heights of parents
        and their children. 
    }%
    \label{fig:galton-interp2}
\end{figure}


\begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.49\textwidth]{galton-interp4}
    \includegraphics[width=.49\textwidth]{galton-inter5}
    \caption{A reconstruction of Galton's method for finding contours of
        approximately equal frequency in the relationship between heights of parents
        and their children. 
    }%
    \label{fig:galton-interp4}
\end{figure}

\chapter{Second}

\begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.49\textwidth]{galton-interp6}
    \includegraphics[width=.49\textwidth]{galton-inter7}
    \caption{A reconstruction of Galton's method for finding contours of
        approximately equal frequency in the relationship between heights of parents
        and their children. 
    }%
    \label{fig:galton-interp5}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Excellent!  I didn't think it would be that easy to solve the file extension problem.

Comment: @user101089: yes, but a nested test with `\IfFileExists` is really tedious. Luckily there are only three possible extensions ;-)