# Generate a list of figure sources from figure captions containing \source{}

Tags: graphics, table-of-contents, captions, external-files

This question stems from the same book project described in [Generate a list of figure numbers and filenames from \includegraphics](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/392370/generate-a-list-of-figure-numbers-and-filenames-from-includegraphics). The answers there provide the basic code to generate a text file of figure numbers and associated file names from LaTeX source. Now, I need to extend this method to a further task of collecting a text file of figure sources.

In this book (nearly) **all** figure `\caption{}`s have included in them a `source{}` command giving the figure source.  It is presently defined just to print information about the figure source as text, with *Source:* in italics

```
\newcommand{\source}[1]{\emph{Source:} #1.}
```

Some figures require permissions, others don't, but for publication, the publisher requires a list of all figures, their sources and permission status.

My desire is to extract at least the basis for this from the LaTeX source by modifying `\source{}` command to also write lines to a **List of Sources** (`los`) file.

One example of a figure requiring permission is:

```
\begin{figure}[htb]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.6\textwidth]{\theChapter/fig/cholera-monmonier-gilbert}
  \caption[\desc{Presentation graphic} Mark Monmonier's re-vision of the Gilbert version of Snow's map, as
  a presentation graphic]{\desc{Presentation graphic} Mark Monmonier's re-vision of the Gilbert version of Snow's map, as
a presentation graphic. \source{Monmonier (1996), \emph{How to Lie with
Maps}, p. 158. Image: permission required, University of Chicago Press.}
}
```

If this is Fig. 4.10 in the book, I'd like the re-defined `\source{}` command to write a line to an `los` file something like:

```
4.10 Monmonier (1996), \emph{How to Lie with Maps}, p. 158. Image: permission required, University of Chicago Press.
```

In other words:
**Wanted**: A way to modify `\source{}` so that it also writes lines to an external file `\jobname.los`, of the form

```
fignum source
```

Can someone help with this?

Answer (score 4):

I took from the linked answer (it's my answer) and added the `\source` command, writing to `.los` with `\addcontentsline` and adding the `\thefigure` such that it is clear which figure and which source belong together.

`\addcontentsline{los}{section}{\thefigure: #1}`

adds the relevant content to the `.los` file with formatting like `section` is done in a regular `ToC`. `\@starttoc{los}` reads the `.los` file and displays it content. The code is quite similar to `\tableofcontents`.

```
\documentclass{book}


\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}


\DeclareRobustCommand{\source}[1]{\emph{Source:} \addcontentsline{los}{section}{\thefigure: #1}#1.}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\listofsources}{%
  \chapter*{List of Sources}
  \@starttoc{los}
  \clearpage
}
\makeatother


\LetLtxMacro\davidsincludegraphics\includegraphics

\makeatletter

\RenewDocumentCommand{\includegraphics}{sO{}mo}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
    \davidsincludegraphics*[#2]{#3}%
  }{%
    \davidsincludegraphics[#2]{#3}%
  }%
  \begingroup
  % Trying to determine the extension
  \def\loc@l@ext{}
  \IfValueTF{#4}{%
    \def\loc@l@ext{#4}%
  }{%
    \IfFileExists{#3}{%
    }{%
      \IfFileExists{#3.pdf}{%
        \edef\loc@l@ext{.pdf}%
      }{%
        \IfFileExists{#3.jpg}{%
          \edef\loc@l@ext{.jpg}%
        }{%
          \edef\loc@l@ext{.png}%
        }%
      }%
    }%
  }%
  \advance\c@figure by \@ne
  \addtocontents{lfn}{\thefigure\space #3\loc@l@ext}
  \endgroup
}

\def\@starttocbutdonotshowit#1{%
  \begingroup
    \makeatletter
    \if@filesw
      \expandafter\newwrite\csname tf@#1\endcsname
      \immediate\openout \csname tf@#1\endcsname \jobname.#1\relax
    \fi
    \@nobreakfalse
  \endgroup}


\newcommand{\listoffigurenumbernames}{%
  \@starttocbutdonotshowit{lfn}%
}



\begin{document}
\listoffigurenumbernames

\listofsources

\chapter{First}

\begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.49\textwidth]{galton-interp2}[.png]
    \includegraphics[width=.49\textwidth]{galton-interp3}
    \caption{A reconstruction of Galton's method for finding contours of
        approximately equal frequency in the relationship between heights of parents
        and their children. \source{Foo stuff}
    }%
    \label{fig:galton-interp2}
\end{figure}


\begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.49\textwidth]{galton-interp4}
    \includegraphics[width=.49\textwidth]{galton-inter5}
    \caption{A reconstruction of Galton's method for finding contours of
        approximately equal frequency in the relationship between heights of parents
        and their children. 
 \source{Monmonier (1996), \emph{How to Lie with
Maps}, p. 158. Image: permission required, University of Chicago Press.}
    }%
    \label{fig:galton-interp4}
\end{figure}

\chapter{Second}

\begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=.49\textwidth]{galton-interp6}
    \includegraphics[width=.49\textwidth]{galton-inter7}
    \caption{A reconstruction of Galton's method for finding contours of
        approximately equal frequency in the relationship between heights of parents
        and their children. 
    }%
    \label{fig:galton-interp5}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Comment: That is a good start. I corrected an error, in that the name for the List of Sources information should be `los`, not `lfn`.

Comment: **Also**:  In my use case, there are situations where I use a `\url{}` inside `\source{}`, e.g., `\source{Library of Congress, \url{http://hdl.loc.gov/loc.pnp/ppmsca.33913}} }`.  I don't know why, but these generate an `undefined control sequence` error.

Comment: **Finally**: I don't really need a "List of Sources" in the Front section, although that is nice and does no harm.  However, in the `\jobname.los` file it would be best if information for each figure was just `fignum figsource`, or `fignum filename figsource` all on on line.  The code above gives me two separate lines for each figure: `1.1 ../ch06-scat/fig/galton-interp2.png` and `\contentsline {section}{1.1: Foo stuff; permission required}{3}`

Comment: @user101089: Sorry, but `.los` and `.lfn` is not really an error. And your question is anything but clear.

Comment: **Sorry**; you were right about `.los` and `.lfn`. What I want is obtained by using just `\DeclareRobustCommand{\source}[1]{\emph{Source:} \addtocontents{los}{\thefigure\space #1}#1.}`