# Figure credit posted inside figure environment, printed in listoffigurecredits

Tags: table-of-contents, floats

I'm writing a long book with many figures, and I'd like to insert figure credit code inside each figure environment and have the associated credit text collected and printed in a Listoffigurecredits (much like a Listoffigures, Listoftables, and such) at the end of the book.

I looked into [this related answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2527/photograph-credits-in-latex) but it was rather complex and did not perform quite what I needed, for instance the automatic numbering of the credit based on the typeset figure number.

As an example, I would like a figure call with associated credit line to be of the (minimal) form:

```
\begin{figure}
\include{...figure file here...}
\caption{Mona Lisa by Leonardo da Vinci.}
\figurecredit{Mona Lisa by Leonardo da Vinci, reproduced by permission, The Louvre, Paris.}
\end{figure}
```

Then, at the end of the book I'd like to have a

```
\listoffigurecredits
```

which would print a list whose items included:

**Figure 2.9:  Mona Lisa by Leonardo da Vinci, reproduced by permission, The Louvre, Paris.**

Notice that the "Figure 2.9" should be automatically generated, based on the actual typeset figure, and that the style should match that of listoffigures, listoftables, etc.

I'm hoping for the minimal code... the simplest approach to this admittedly tricky task.

Comment: The code in the linked answers isn't tricky really. There is much more trickier content on this site, of course

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

The macro `\figurecredits` just writes the credit to a separate file named `\jobname.fcf` and `\listoffigurecredits` is basically nothing different than a copy of `\tableofcontents`, which displays the `.fcf` file.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}


\makeatletter
\newcommand{\figurecredit}[2][]{%
  \ifblank{#1}{%
    \addcontentsline{fcf}{figure}{\protect\numberline{\thefigure}#2}%
  }{%
    \addcontentsline{fcf}{figure}{\protect\numberline{\thefigure}#1}%
  }%
}

\newcommand{\listoffigurecredits}{%
  \begingroup
  \clearpage
  \let\old@starttoc\@starttoc
  \def\@starttoc##1{\old@starttoc{fcf}}
  \renewcommand{\contentsname}{Figure credits}
  \tableofcontents
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\listoffigures


\begin{figure}
\caption{Mona Lisa by Leonardo da Vinci.}
\figurecredit{Mona Lisa by Leonardo da Vinci, reproduced by permission, The Louvre, Paris.}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\caption{The Scream by Edvard Munch}
\figurecredit[The Scream]{The Scream by Edvard Munch}
\end{figure}


\listoffigurecredits

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks so very much.  Let me run this later today and if (as I suspect) it works with tufte-book, I'll accept your answer.

Comment: You code *almost* works (+1) in the tufte-book environment.  It indeed lists the \figurecredit text, but it does *not* insert the full figure number beforehand, e.g., Figure 2.9 (which includes the chapter).  I tried adding \thechapter and \thefigure inside the figurecredit text, but of course that does not give the proper listing on the *Figure credits* page.  How to fix this?

Comment: Ah... I see the problem:  tufte-book numbers the figures sequentially, without regard to chapter.  I'll have to change *that* style, and then presumably the numbering will appear proper in the *Figure credits*.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork: Things `tufte` screws up are not my fault. ;-) If `\thefigure` is define differently you have to change it, of course.

Comment: Well, I wouldn't say Tufte's followers "screwed up," it is just a stylistic choice.  And frankly I think Tufte's original books and several by others using tufte-book are some of the most elegant and readable in any form.  Bottom line:  You've done your job.  Thanks so much.  (accept)

Comment: It works for me in this minimal example (even after switching the class to scrbook) but not inside a large scrbook document, where I get no fcf file and the standard toc being printed at \listoffigurecredits. Any idea what could be going wrong? Bonus question, I’ve read that tocbasic should be used to implement something like this, but I haven’t managed too. Did you ever look at it?

Comment: Finally found ways by myself, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/506607/56823

Answer (score 3):

Based on @user31729 answer as well as [this other one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/411609/56823), here is a more minimalist case that worked for me where @user31729 answer did not:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\figurecredit}[1]{\addcontentsline{fcf}{figure}{\protect\numberline{\thefigure}#1}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\listoffigurecredits}{%
    \begingroup
    \chapter*{Figure credits}
    \@starttoc{fcf}
    \endgroup
}
\makeatother
```

Now, if you use a KOMA-Script class, or even just `tocbasic` by itself, you can also do this:

```
\addtotoclist[]{fcf}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\figurecredit}[1]{\addcontentsline{fcf}{figure}{\protect\numberline{\thefigure}#1}}
\newcommand*{\listoffigurecredits}{\listoftoc[Figures credits]{fcf}}
```

Finally, you might want subfigures to be included and properly referenced, then swap the definition of `\figurecredit` with:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\figurecredit}[1]{%
    \addcontentsline{fcf}{figure}{%
        \ifnum\value{subfigure}>0
            \protect\numberline{\thefigure.\thesubfigure}
        \else
            \protect\numberline{\thefigure}
        \fi
        #1%
    }%
}
```

Comment: This solution works great for me!

Answer (score 0):

This may not be satisfying, but the quick and dirty solution would be to put all the text inside the caption, then use the command \listoffigures which generates a list of all figures first with figure number then the caption text (separated by a colon).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Sorry, the OP wants to get two lists, one list of figures as usual and a second list with the credits. I think you missunderstood the question Am I right?

Comment: Yeah sorry, my bad.

Comment: @JoeThePhysWiz:  Alas, I have a separate \listoffigures which is separate from the figurecredits, so your approach won't work.