# How to get a list of valid commands?

Tags: packages, auto-completion

I want to dynamically create a list of LaTeX commands that are valid in a particular file based on the packages used so that I can use them for code completion.

Does LaTeX provide a method for checking whether commands are commands (besides attempting to compile), or better, for obtaining a list of commands in a package? I don't care what kind of argument they have to take etc for my purpose (though if they have to have certain arrangements of braces afterward, that could be relevant). It *is* significant whether they work in math mode and whether they work out of it.

Failing that, is there a simple way to parse TeX files and packages to obtain all packages used and all commands therein?

Comment: No, this is not possible. Packages may define commands dynamically or in very contorted ways. Just by way of example, `algpseudocode` uses `\algdef` or `\algnewcommand` for defining its commands.

Comment: this question tells how to identify all the packages used in a job: [Create list of all external files used by master LaTeX document?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24542/579).  getting a list of all commands is an entirely different matter.

Comment: AUCTeX for Emacs does syntax coloring (and completion although I never tried to learn the key strokes for that) of know commands, but the developers must maintain a database (sort of) of the known packages ; by necessity this is only partial. Possibly other integrated editors for LaTeX have such database incorporated. I don't know actually if "database" is the technically appropriate term. AUCTeX must have "style" files for each LaTeX package it knows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it is not possible. Packages may define commands in several ways, besides the standard `\def` (and variants) or `\newcommand` and `\DeclareRobustCommand`. Consider for instance, `\DeclareMathSymbol` or `\DeclareTextCommand` (but there are other ways even in the LaTeX kernel).

Just to make a few examples, `algpseudocode` uses `\algdef` and `\algnewcommand`; other package have their own methods. They can even define commands dynamically based on user input. Other commands may have “limited life” (think to the unit names for `siunitx`) and different syntax depending on where they're called.

The list should also exclude all internal commands and others such as `\temp` `\next` or `\do` that are used as scratch macro names.

As regards to syntax, consider that, for instance, `memoir` redefines `\chapter` and the other sectional commands to have *two* optional arguments, rather than one. Other packages might define `*`-variants of existing commands, and in order to discover this you need to analyze the definition itself: basically, if `\foo` is defined and a package wants to add a `*`-variant, we would find something like

```
\let\org@foo\foo
\renewcommand{\foo}{\@ifstar\foo@star\org@foo}
\newcommand{\foo@star}{...<whatever>...}
```

The number of packages and commands they define is huge. Really. Doing a lexical analysis of just the packages loaded by the user would mean following all `\RequirePackage` in called ones. And maybe some of them are only loaded conditionally. Not to mention that commands might be defined in other files input by packages, so you should follow also `\input` and similar commands.

Good luck. `;-)`