# Copy all graphics files called by a LaTeX document in a subdirectory, irrespective of its original path?

Tags: input, includegraphics

I want an easy (automatic) way to copy all image files called by latex into as single directory. A similar issue was addressed here: [Create list of all external files used by master LaTeX document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24542/create-list-of-all-external-files-used-by-master-latex-document)
and I like the solution proposed by @imriss except that it requires all files to reside in the same directory as the tex file to work. Some of my image file reside elsewhere and are accessed through TEXINPUTS and are not found by this technique because the dep file produced by snapshot only contains the names of the files, not their path.

Comment: You should probably look up `\graphicspath` see http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex-dev/graphics/grfguide.pdf section 4.5

Comment: To get a list of all used graphic files, with full file path: Compiling with `pdflatex -recorder xxx.main` will create an aux file `xxx.fls` which contains a full (with repetition) list of input and output files, with full file path. Then parse this `xxx.fls` by file extensions.

Answer (score 2):

Building of @muzimuzhi Z's comment and @imriss' answer to the question [Create list of all external files used by master LaTeX document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24542/create-list-of-all-external-files-used-by-master-latex-document), here is way to copy all external files used by a latex doc to the directory `img`, based on a choice of file extensions.

Starting with a latex file `file.tex` type

```
pdflatex -recover file
```

which creates `file.fls`. Create a file, say `copy_fig_fls.py`, containing the following python code:

```
"""Copy figures used by document."""
import os
import shutil

FLS_FILE = 'file.fls'
TARGET_DIR = 'img/'
EXTENSIONS = ['pdf', 'png', 'jpg']

def copy_image_files():
    with open(FLS_FILE, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            if 'INPUT' not in line:
                continue
            source = line.split(' ')[1].rstrip()
            _, e = os.path.splitext(source)
            e = e.lower()[1:]
            if e in EXTENSIONS:
                shutil.copy(source, TARGET_DIR)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    copy_image_files()
```

Run it by typing

```
python3 copy_fig_fls.py
```

It will copy all the files used by `file.tex` with extensions listed in the `EXTENSIONS` variable into the `img` directory, irrespective of where the original image file resides, in the current directory or elsewhere.