# Clean project from unnecessary files not needed for compilation

Tags: compiling, filesystem-access

I was wondering whether there's an automated way to detect unnecessary files (not auxiliary files) that are not needed for compilation of a LaTeX document, perhaps during or after compilation? For research articles I usually brute force it: for instance I change the name of the `figures` folder to `figures2` and create a new `figures` folder, and then compile/copy missing file iteratively from `figures2` to `figures` until the document compiles. I then delete whatever was left in `folders2`.

This is doable for small projects. Now I've been working on a book for a couple of years and the project is near completion. This project has gotten so big that the brute force approach is not possible. I would appreciate any tips in getting this automated.

**EDIT**
It was suggested to use the `snapshot` package as discussed [in this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24542/create-list-of-all-external-files-used-by-master-latex-document). I tried this and it's helpful, but it still requires some manual intervention because it tells you what are the files that are needed instead of those that are *not* needed by traversing a hierarchy.

Comment: Add `\listfiles` as first line of your main file, and check the end of the log output. It will, however, list all the style fles loaded from the TeX distribution.